# Orderings on a space such that every initial segment has measure 0

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\mu,X,\Sigma)$ be an atomless probability measure. Is it alway possible to find a well-ordering of $X$, $<$, such that for any $x\in X$, $Pr(\{y\mid y<x\})=0$?

(Edit: I'd also be interested in an answer to the weaker claim: it is always possible to find a well-ordering such that for every $x\in X$ such that $\{y\mid y<x\}$ is measureable, $Pr(\{y\mid y<x\})=0$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consistently no. For example, add $\omega_2$ random reals to a model of CH. In this model, there is a (Sierpinski) set $X$ of size $\omega_2 = 2^{\aleph_0}$ each one of whose uncountable subsets is non null so any well ordering of reals has an initial segment that contains exactly $\aleph_1$ points of $X$ and hence is proper and non null.

On the other hand, under CH, any measure space made by pasting together the product measures on $2^{\kappa}$'s cannot be a counterexample - Since we can partition them into $\aleph_1$ null sets and put them next to each other.

This doesn't rule out a ZFC counterexample. Unfortunately, I don't know any examples of atomless probability measure spaces which are essentially different from the above. By Maharam's theorem, we know that their measure algebras are essentially made of the measure algebras of $2^{\kappa}$'s but this doesn't seem to help.

If we only require that the measurable initial segments be null, then once again pasting together $2^{\kappa}$ doesn't work due to inner regularity. So I don't even know if this can be consistently false.